# Struggling trying to migrate from Ethereum wallet to

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

Ok here is my sitation.

1. I have some ETH that was stored on an old laptop.
2. I have not run the wallet application for well over a year on the old laptop but I do have a backup of the keystore on my new one so I should not need to update the software and watch it try to sync for days I assume on the old laptop?
3. Instead I want to migrate over to using Mist from Ethereum Wallet using this keystore on the new laptop. I assume that possible is it?
4. Downloading and installing mist just gave an error and told me to update to geth 1.8.23 so I did that. I am running latest version of windows.
5. When I now run mist I don't get the error but it's stuck on "connecting". When I click on the red dot in the bottom corner it says "Local node looking for peers" and "remote node connecting" but never connects.

What are my next steps and why isn't this working?

Also how to I import my old keystore when getting past this part?

Comment: Note that [both Ethereum Wallet and Mist are deprecated](https://avsa.medium.com/sunsetting-mist-da21c8e943d2).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have keystore JSON file from the laptop, and then the password for it.

Then you can import the keystore to [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.com/).

Comment: In order to remember the password, what were the password requirements for creating an account on Ethereum wallet?

Was it ... 
10 chars min
uppercase,lowercase,
number,
symbol

Or was it ...
8 chars min
uppercase,lowercase,
number,
symbol

Comment: I do not think there were any requirements. If you have lost your password here is a service that can crack the password for you: https://keychainx.com/

Comment: Pretty sure there was a requirement. Anyone know what it is?